# Find the equation of an exponential function knowing that its gradient=y coordinate

Tags: exponential-function

Find the equation of an exponential function knowing that its gradient=y coordinate.

$f(x)=k^x$
   What values would have to take $k$?

The $y$ coordinate has to be equal to the gradient, e.g. in $y=1$, the gradient has to be $1$.

Comment: Do you mean $y'(x)=y(x)$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, I added some information to try to make it clearer.

Comment: You mean like an $e^x$ function? Because if you take the derivative of it and substitute in an x you get the y-coordinate of the original function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are given that

$$f(x)=k^x$$

then $$f'(x)=k^x\log k=f(x)$$ is achieved when $$\log k=1.$$